# Combined Pearson/Spearman rank correlation matrix with significance stars in Stata

Tags: matrix, latex, stata, correlation

I want to calculate a correlation matrix, where the lower triangle consists of Pearson and the upper triangle consists of Spearman rank correlation coefficients.
I am using `corr` and `spearman`, which works fine. But with `corr` I cannot get the significance (p-value or stars and so on). So I tried `pwcorr, list` which gives me the exact results but with significance.

Using this "new combination" I cannot create the matrix as with `corr`.

```
//Get Pearson Matrix
corr var1 var2 var3

matrix R = r(C)

//Get Row and Column Names
local rnames : rownames R
local cnames : colnames R

//Get Spearman Rank Matrix
spearman var1 var2 var3, matrix star(0.05)
matrix S = r(Rho)

//Convert Pearson Matrix to Mata Matrix
mata: mataR = st_matrix("R")

//Convert Spearman Rank Matrix to Mata Matrix
mata: mataS = st_matrix("S")

//Clone Mata Pearson Matrix for Combined mataRS Mata Matrix
//Pearsson and Spearman Rank Matrix in Mata
mata: mataRS = mataR

//Replace Pearson r with Spearman rho in Top Half of Combined mataRS Mata Matrix
mata: mataRS[1,2] = mataS[2,1]
mata.... and so on.

//Display Pearson, Spearman Rank, and combined Matrices in Mata
mata: mataR
mata: mataS
mata: mataRS

//Convert combined mataRS Mata Matrix to Stata Matrix RS
mata: st_matrix("RS", mataRS)
matrix rownames RS = `rnames'
matrix colnames RS = `cnames'

//Display combined Stata Matrix RS
matlist RS, format(%8.4f)
```

When I replace `corr` with `pwcorr, list` I get the following error:

```
mata: mataRS[1,2] = mataS[2,1]
<istmt>:  3301  subscript invalid" for the command
```

(The code using is taken from http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2014-01/msg00349.html.)

Is there a "smart" way to solve this? (By the way, I am working with TeXMaker, so it would be great if the output can be transferred for LaTeX.)

Answer (score 1):

This approach adopts the method from Ben Jann's [`estout` documentation](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/advanced.html#advanced908) mostly out of Friday afternoon laziness, and uses the fact that Spearman correlation is just Pearson correlation on ranks. Stacking the ranks and the raw data in the same variable makes stitching this Frankenmatrix somewhat easier.

It takes a variable list and produces a LaTeX file that contains Pearson correlations below the main diagonal and Spearman correlations above it. Both will have significance stars.

```
eststo clear
set more off
sysuse auto, clear
capture ssc install estout

local vlist "price mpg weight"
local upper
local lower `vlist'

expand 2, gen(version)

foreach v of local vlist {
    egen rank = rank(`v') if version == 1
    replace `v' = rank if version ==1
    drop rank
}

foreach v of local vlist {

   estpost correlate `v' `lower' if version == 0
   foreach m in b rho p count {
       matrix `m' = e(`m')
   }

   if "`upper'"!="" {
   estpost correlate `v' `upper' if version == 1
       foreach m in b rho p count {
           matrix `m' = e(`m'), `m'
       }
   }
   ereturn post b
   foreach m in rho p count {
       quietly estadd matrix `m' = `m'
   }
   eststo `v', title(`v')
   local lower: list lower - v
   local upper `upper' `v'
 }

/* Export the LaTeX matrix */
esttab using "frankenmatrix.tex", nonumbers mtitles noobs not tex replace title("Correlations")

/* Clean up the data and make sure we did things right */
drop if version ==1
drop version

corr `vlist'
spearman `vlist'
```

You should use `\input{frankenmatrix.tex}` in your tex document to incorporate this file. The output should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Dear Dimitriy, Thank you for your code. It works fine, but I do get different results from the code used above. Let´s say I have 5 variables A B C D E, of which A, B and C there are two versions: 1) A, B and C (normal) and 2) already ranked A, B, and C.

Comment: @eternity1 I am not entirely sure what you're asking. First, your code does not seem to produce the right Spearman values because you have not completed the "mata.... and so on." step. You would need to add a step for each Spearman cell to match the output of `spearman`. The second part makes no sense to me. My code creates ranked versions of the variables for you. You don't need to do it. The differences could be explained by how you are adjusting for ties in calculating the ranks (equal observations should assigned the average rank with Spearman) if you are doing it manually.

Comment: Dear Dimitriy, I am sorry for confusing you. For example: I have var1, var2, var3, var4. My analysis is done with transformed variable: var1 and var2 are ranked (manually) to dvar1 and dvar2. So what I want is to have a Pearson Correlation Matrix with dvar1, dvar2, var3 and var4. The Spearman Rank Correlation should include var1, var2, var3 and var4. Spearman is supposed to "work" with the original variable var1, var2 because it makes no sense (for my study) to rank an already ranked variable. Thank you :)

Comment: Dear Dimitriy, I have trouble to export this table to excel as a csv-file. it works fine if I use a "simple" version: 
estpost correlate adsue1 adsue2 adsue3 dspot dslope dleverage dvola upgrade downgrade index_bhar index_casc, matrix list
esttab . using P_correlation_csv.csv, not unstack noobs title("Pearson Correlation matrix") nonumber replace

Comment: I thought you wanted the output as LaTeX?

Comment: Yes, initally I wanted it as LaTeX, but as it turns out, I need the raw csv file too. Is that possible?

Comment: You can `esttab using matrix.csv, nonumbers mtitles noobs not`. I think this is verging on new question territory.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the thread you cited on (old) Statalist. It points to `corsp`, a user-written command on SSC that also produces p-values.

As for export to LaTeX, there are several user-written commands, just type `findit latex` in Stata.